# Agora cloud recording is started successfully but not recording

Tags: javascript, node.js, live-streaming, agora.io, agora-web-sdk-ng

Steps:

1. Acquire: success, got resourceId
2. Start: success, got sid
3. query: first got success but then, code 404

From the browser, I have joined with 2 users in a channel `test1` and uids are 100 and 101.

For recording, I got resourceId for recording using uid 99 (On backend side)

```
//Accquire
let reqBody = {
    "cname": 'test1',
    "uid": '99',
    "clientRequest": {}
};
```

Then I hit start API.

```
 //start
 let reqBody = {
            "cname": 'test1',
            "uid": 99,
            "clientRequest": {
                "token": channelRecorderToken,
                "storageConfig": {
                    "secretKey": ("awsSecretKey"),
                    "region": storageRegion,
                    "accessKey": ("awsAccessKey"),
                    "bucket": ("awsBucket"),
                    "vendor": storageVendor,
                    "fileNamePrefix": [
                        "RECORDINGS"
                    ]
                },
            }
        };
```

AWS settings are correct, I checked multiple times. For generating token I used this,

```
let channelRecorderToken = RtcTokenBuilder.buildTokenWithUid(appID, appCertificate, channelName, userId, role, privilegeExpiredTs);
```

QUERY RESPONSE:

```
// RESPONSE 1
{
"resourceId": "resourceId",
"sid": "sid",
"serverResponse": {
    "status": 4,
    "fileList": "",
    "fileListMode": "string",
    "sliceStartTime": 0
}
}

// RESPONSE 2: When I again hit query API after 5-10 seconds 
{
   "resourceId": "resourceId",
   "sid": "sid",
   "code": 404
}
```

Comment: I'm having the same issue. Did you ever resolve this? Is the AWS bucket just the bucket name (ex. my-bucket) or is it the ARN (arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket)? I too have checked permissions and everything is setup correctly. I added CORS headers PUT and POST to the bucket as well to make sure.

Comment: Yes! ... My issue was sending the wrong vendor & storageRegion... And for bucket name simply pass my-bucket